# Property Events in Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I recently installed visual studio 2019 on my PC but the problem was that, I cannot see the property events below the tabs. You can view the image to see how it works thank you very much! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the "Navigation Bar":

```
Main Menu > Tools > Options


Text Editor >
    Basic >

            [X] Navigation bar
```